# How to resolve node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942 throw err?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, graphql

I am trying to run the following commands

```
npm run graphql-codegen init
npm run install
```

But it always throws an error which is that it is unable to find the graphql-codegen module. [image: Error Image]

My package.json file looks like this.
[image]

Can anybody please tell me what is issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct command:

```
npx graphql-codegen init
```